Proxmox linux bridge has binded ip which not works 50% of time
I have default proxmox install on Vultr baremetal server
It has bridge like this
root@ed2:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp1s0 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 66.42.104.XXX/23
        gateway 66.42.104.1
        bridge-ports enp1s0
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0


source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

50% of time(EXACTLY) ip 66.42.104.XXX is not reachable from external world.
Same time it is reachable from any internal ip. Internal ips are public and accessable without issues from outside.
STP turned off. IPV6 turned off. iptables and ebtables show zero configuration.
Tcpdump can see incoming ping packets on vmbr0 when ip is unreachable.
What am I missing here?
